# A value of type toolbar cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type Collection

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017, toolbar

I get the error described in the title using Toolbar(s) in a ToolBarTray like the following:

```
<ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ToolBar>
            <Button Command="New" Content="New" />
            <Button Command="Open" Content="Open" />
            <Button Command="Save" Content="Save" />
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar>
            <Button Command="Cut" Content="Cut" />
            <Button Command="Copy" Content="Copy" />
            <Button Command="Paste" Content="Paste" />
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
```

I can compile the program, it works perfectly, but I continue to get the error in Visual Studio.
Looks like I'm missing something, but I have no clue of what it is...

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

**Edit** Problem magically disappeared. The only thing I can say is that this morning I did a reboot (I'm not sure if I did reboots while having the error: I often hybernate my machine).

Comment: You can compile and run (?) the application but "continue to get the error in Visual Studio". When do you get the error then? And please post your full XAML markup.

Comment: As soon as I read your comment, I went back to the code giving me error and with some surprise ... it no longer appears (today I was working on something else). The error was being displayed all the time, even after closing and reopening Visual Studio, recompiling all the project or the whole solution... I don't remember if I did some reboots in last days, but certainly I did this morning: maybe this morning reboot fixed the problem? I hate wasting time for no-solution problems... thanks for your interest, whatever the problem was I hope next Update will fix this strange behaviors...